# clear cache page from production

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I have a PHP page on production which displays the data from MySQL in XML format. I deleted the data from the database. But it still displays the old XML data from yesterday. I just entered a new record but still display the data from yesterday. I  am using the following code to clear the cache but didn't work. I am stuck with this issue. Please let me know if there are any suggestions. Thanks for your help.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Comment: just an odd comment, but try appending a `?` to your url to make the browser fetch everything again and see if that works

Comment: I appended ? to the url. Now it works. Is it safe solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Eli, Do you know how to reset the form(clear all fields data) when browser back button is pressed? I have used the above code to clear the cache but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably your browser.

- hit CTRL and F5
- Try clearing your history and cache
- And if your using
  Chrome (which is a notorious cache'r) press CTRL SHIFT j click the
  cog in the bottom right and disable cache

Answer (score 0):

Try `session_cache_limiter` function if you have a session. ( Call this before `session_start` function )

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
```